# how we can receive particular row from a sql data base in android studio

Tags: android, sql, database, sqlite, android-studio

Iam working on a android studio project in which i have to receive data of a particular name clicked from my list vie,data is stored in sql in form of table,
for example i person click name "maira" it should receive data of maira from the database table.

here is my code of item class here message is the name of item clicked in listview in main activity

```
 `public class Itemshow extends AppCompatActivity {
SQLiteOpenHelper sqLiteOpenHelper;
TextView nameCustomer;
TextView phoneCustomer;
TextView medicinesCustomer;
String message;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_itemshow);



    Bundle bundle=getIntent().getExtras();
    if(bundle!=null)
        message=bundle.getString("item");
    nameCustomer=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.nameTextView);
    nameCustomer.setText(message);


    DatabaseHelper db;
    db=new DatabaseHelper(this);


    Cursor answer = db.getDataForGivenName(message);

    while (answer.moveToNext()){
        // some examples, you can continue from here
        String temp = answer.getString(0);  //0 is the index of the column ID
        String temp2 = answer.getString(1); //1 is the index of the column CUSTOMER_NAME
        // You can possible ad them in Arraylist if you need this data somewhere else
    }




}
```

}

`

and my data base helper class is

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
public static final String DATABASE_NAME="Chemist.db";
public static final String TABLE_NAME="chemist_table";
public static final String COL_1="ID";
public static final String COL_2 ="CUSTOMER_NAME";
public static final String COL_3="CUSTOMER_PHONE";
public static final String COL_4="MEDICINES";



public DatabaseHelper( Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("create table "+ TABLE_NAME + " (CUSTOMER_NAME TEXT PRIMARY KEY,CUSTOMER_PHONE TEXT,MEDICINES TEXT)");

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+TABLE_NAME);
    onCreate(db);

}

public boolean insertData(String customerName,String phone,String medicines )
{
    SQLiteDatabase db=this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues=new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(COL_2,customerName);
    contentValues.put(COL_3,phone);
    contentValues.put(COL_4,medicines);
    long result=db.insert(TABLE_NAME,null,contentValues);
    if (result==-1)
        return false;
    else
        return true;

}

public Cursor getAllData(){
    SQLiteDatabase db=this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor res=db.rawQuery("select * from "+TABLE_NAME,null);
    return res;
}
public Cursor getDataForGivenName(String name){
    SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor result = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE NAME = '" + name + "'", null);
    return result;
}
```

}

i am not able to do it can you please help me. i just wanted to show data of item from all the columns clicked in listview

Comment: you should post your code of main activity where your list view is clicked.

Comment: @pskink PAN there is only one error  iam facing that when i use     `Cursor answer = db.getDataForGivenName(message);`
my app crashes,please can you give me solution for that

Comment: @pskink That is a fact but what i am doing here is not adding same names in my database,then why the app is crashing ??

Comment: no i am simply using theList.getItemAtposition(1).toString and passing it using key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start by adding a method for getting all data for the given name e.g "maira"

```
 public Cursor getDataForGivenName(String name){
            SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = this.getWritableDatabase();
            Cursor result = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE NAME = '" + name + "'", null);
            return result;
        }
```

Then in your database helper just add

```
Cursor answer = sqLiteHelper.getDataForGivenName(message);
```

And receive all the data you need like:

```
while (answer.moveToNext()){
    // some examples, you can continue from here
    String temp = answer.getString(0);  //0 is the index of the column ID
    String temp2 = answer.getString(1); //1 is the index of the column CUSTOMER_NAME
    // You can possible ad them in Arraylist if you need this data somewhere else       
  }
```

Notice that before you go to this step, you need to get the name (miara) from the list with names, you can do this buy setting some `onclick` listeners

Comment: `Cursor answer = sqLiteHelper.getDataForGivenName(message)`; This line when entered in itemShow.class is crashing the application

Comment: There is no error by my app crashes when i open the item  @Beasteca,i can show you my debugger error `java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{androidsingh.navjyotsingh.chemisthelper/androidsingh.navjyotsingh.chemisthelper.Itemshow}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.database.Cursor androidsingh.navjyotsingh.chemisthelper.DatabaseHelper.getDataForGivenName(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference`

Comment: Yes, but there should be some stacktrace after the crash. You can find it under 'Run' on the bottom part of you screen.

Comment: You need to initialize your dbHelper in the activity class.

Comment: `DatabaseHelper db;`  and then `db = new DatabaseHelper(this);` in the `onCreate()` method of the activity

Comment: After adding this also ,my app crashes when i selected the list item.But when i remove this line `    Cursor answer = db.getDataForGivenName(message);` the application is running perfectly @Beasteca

Comment: why i am not able to retreive data? @Beasteca

Comment: is message = to the name of you listview?

Comment: message= name of the item clicked in list view (whose data we want to retreive) for cross checking it i used a text view to show name and its working perfectly fine.

Comment: yes i saw it , no message is not the name of list view ,its the string name of item clicked, i am again updating the code,after all your corrections